# Left-align equation previews (Auctex)

Tags: latex, auctex, preview-latex

I would like to left-align equations in Auctex's preview's generated by preview-latex. I imagine that this would involve putting `fleqn` in the `documentclass` options in whatever latex file things are generated from.

How can I do this? I have tried to find this location but have not had much success.

Comment: Preview runs LaTeX with `preview-LaTeX-command` on the same files as the functions `TeX-command-*` do. For an instance, `preview-document` runs on the TeX-master document. So the difference really comes from `preview-LaTeX-command`.

Comment: Note, putting `fleqn` into the class options of the actual document works for me.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `align`? You can use `align` as follows,

```tex
\begin{align}
x &= y + z\\
\beta &= \alpha\gamma
\end{align}
```

Comment: I mean justifying the generated images to the left without altering the underlying text. this can be done in latex using the `fleqn` documentclass option